# Can I enter the Netherlands with a car rented in Germany?

Tags: germany, car-rentals, netherlands

I just booked a car via [Check24](https://mietwagen.check24.de/) for a couple of days, but I couldn't find any information on whether I could drive the car outside Germany, specifically Amsterdam.

Is it allowed to drive to the Netherlands? My guess is that since both countries are inside the Schengen area, it is possible to drive there (but I'm not sure).

**PS:** I'm not a German citizen. I'm Southeastern European.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be stopped at the border and most likely your rental car company will not get to know that you crossed the border -- that is, unless you will be involved in a car accident or get a speeding (or parking) ticket.

All rental contracts are different, however, and hence you really need to look it up in the terms and condition of your rental contract. Check24 only acts as a search engine, though, and despite the fact that their interface suggests otherwise, your rental contract will be with another company.

Note that insurance is often split if you book a cheap fare with a full-service insurance package - the car rental company (e.g., Avis) will provide the basic insurance, and the collision damage waiver will be provided by a different insurance company - in this case you will need to read two sets of terms & conditions.

The T&C are best checked before booking the car. Should you use the German version of the *check24* web page, click on "Details und Mietbedingungen" (Details & T&C) below the offer and then click on "Mietbedingungen". I just checked a random offer, where the following is written about taking the car abroad:

> Westeuropa: Fahrten sind in alle westeuropäischen Länder erlaubt. Alle
>   bereisten Länder müssen zum Buchungszeitpunkt angegeben und auf dem
>   Voucher vermerkt werden

Translated to English this means:

> Western Europe: Journey to all western European countries are permitted. All countries travelled through (and within) must be listed at the time of booking and must be listed on the rental car voucher.

So for this offer, you can only take your car abroad to the Netherlands if you notify the rental car company *at the time of booking*. This could be the case for your offer as well.

Comment: I rented a car from Enterprise at the Dusseldorf airport, told them I was driving it to the Netherlands for a week when they asked, and they added something like a €6/day charge. I had considered not mentioning it, but I didn't want to risk trouble in the event of an accident/ticket.